# How to set orthographic near/far clipping planes to display all vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering, glm-math

I am rendering scenes using a `glm::ortho` projection. I want the rendering to include every vertex I draw without adding unnecessary depth (i.e. with minimal depth buffer resolution impact).

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101119/how-do-i-methodically-choose-the-near-clip-plane-distance-for-a-perspective-proj) post for a similar question on perspective projections, but I am looking for both near and far clipping plane values in an orthographic projection.

I can calculate the z values of each vertex using the viewMatrix to transform the vertices into screen coordinates. In pseudo code:

```
float near;
float far;

for (each glm::vec4 vertex)
{
    glm::vec4 trans = viewMatrix * vertex;
    // invert for z-buffer
    trans.z = -trans.z;
    if (trans.z < near)
        near = trans.z;
    if (trans.z > far)
        far = trans.z;
}
```

This way, `near` and `far` represent the z-values of the nearest and farthest vertices in screen coordinates, respectively.

But when I use these values as `zNear` and `zFar` in the `glm::ortho` matrix, much of the rendering is still clipped. What am I missing?

Comment: Don;t you use model matrices?