# Material shines through when zooming out (three.js r78)

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

## Material shines through when zooming out (three.js r78)

When zooming out to a certain extend the material of objects behind other objects starts to shine through. It looks very similar to the effect when faces are overlapping (faces are in the same plane).

To demonstrate this I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/8rv8cguL/).

In this example I draw two thin boxes (thickness 1 and there is a empty space between the boxes of
also 1) so the boxes are not touching eachother but the material shines through anyway.

```
// geometry with thickness 1
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(20000, 20000, 1);
```

This screenshot demonstrates the effect:
[image]

This screenshot shows there is a space between the two geometries.
[image]

When zooming the effect sometimes appears and sometimes disappears (it is also depending on zoom distance and the size of the screen).

I tried to play around with different material properties, but I seem to be unable to find any material setting that prevents this from happening.

Is this a bug? Or a WebGL limitation? Or a general limitation in 3D graphics?
Or am I missing something and is this actually a material or renderer configuration mistake?

In my models this effect is really disturbing and ugly. Can I somehow prevent this from happening?

Comment: is this ok https://jsfiddle.net/8rv8cguL/5/ .taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26747759/ugly-render-on-clouds

Comment: @FastSnail Seems like a great solution. Can you elaborate on the working of this parameter in an answer then I will accept it. I also got another suggestion [on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9148#issuecomment-226457745) but maybe your suggestion is even better.

Comment: i really don't know the answer but tried above answer and got it work.according to it setting `logarithmicDepthBuffer: true` works.but i think it's better if you write a answer with both solution because you know it well.

Comment: @FastSnail Sure! Thanks for the suggestion anyway, just wanted to give you the credits for it. I will see what else I get and then I will answer the question myself a bit later...

Comment: i remember this video from udacity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CjckWVwd2ek. it may also help

Comment: I never had this problem zooming in or out, for me it is whenever the angle of the camera ceases to be DIRECTLY at the object in question. 15 degrees of freedom is all I ever seem to get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This problem is caused by a faulty configuration that severely limits the depth buffer precision.
On [OpenGL.org](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision) it is described as follows:

> *You may have configured your `zNear` and `zFar` clipping planes in a way that severely limits your depth buffer precision. Generally, this is caused by a `zNear` clipping plane value that's too close to `0.0`. As the `zNear` clipping plane is set increasingly closer to `0.0`, the effective precision of the depth buffer decreases dramatically. Moving the `zFar` clipping plane further away from the eye always has a negative impact on depth buffer precision, but it's not one as dramatic as moving the `zNear` clipping plane.*

True, since in the example the near clipping plane value was set to `1`.
So far I know two solutions to this problem.

---

**1) Simply increase the camera `near` value:**

```
// camera
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 
    500, // <-- Increased near from 1 to 500
    150000
);
```

This solution is demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/8rv8cguL/6/)

- The solution was suggested by @WestLangley [here on GitHub](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/9148#issuecomment-226457745)
- Refer to [that OpenGL.org page](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Depth_Buffer_Precision) for more background information
- [Here a nice question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8101119/1697459) about deciding on your near clipping plane values

---

**2) Configure the WebGL renderer to use a logarithmic depth buffer:**

```
// renderer
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    logarithmicDepthBuffer: true // <-- Set render to use logarithmic depth buffer
});
```

This solution is demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/8rv8cguL/5/)

- This solution was suggested by @FastSnail in his comment and comes from [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26748408/1697459)
- See also an OpenGL demo on logarithmic VS normal depth buffer in [this YouTube movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TtEYYf2r0BE)
- And another demo specifically for three.js / WebGL in [this YouTube movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UJzK-qsyGxU)
- Refer also to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364930/logarithmic-depth-buffer-opengl) for more background on logarithmic depth buffer

---

### *Please post another answer in case you know any other solutions.*

Comment: Wilt - You need to explain why increasing the near plane works. : - )

Comment: @WestLangley I actually have no idea, please feel free to edit or answer... I also have no clue why setting `logarithmicDepthBuffer` works. What is even more interesting to know is how all this influences performance.

Comment: If you can provide a link with some background I can also add this info myself (I am not lazy, I simply don't know).

Comment: Wilt - Google "depth buffer precision".

Comment: Will it work for all model?I have tested it,with most of the model this condition helps but with some model it fails.Can anyone please guide me to a generic solution.

Comment: logarithmicDepthBuffer not working in three_70.can anyone guide me in this?

Comment: @Aashajoney can you be more specific on the type of model for which it doesn't work. Logaritmic depth buffer should work. It has been moved to a `WebGLCapabilities` class, but it still exists. Check the class [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLCapabilities.js#L69) for reference

Comment: @Wilt  I am trying to load a CAD/CAM model of a car with huge count of vertices and faces.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462145/three-js-z-fighting?noredirect=1#comment70135459_41462145 .Can you take your time to look at this link.