# Three.js Z fighting

Tags: javascript, three.js

[image: model I am working with]

While moving and zooming a model I am facing this problem.Looking weird.

Tried setting `logarithmicDepthBuffer:true` in webgl renderer and near value of perspective camera to higher as suggested(1000).But the result is not fruitful.

Can anyone help me with different answer.
Any suggestion is welcome
Thanks in advance

Comment: You probably mean you changed the far value to 1000. How close are those polygons anyway? Maybe https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2593

Comment: Tried setting those values too

Comment: If you add a fiddle to your question it would be easier to help you.